# Use html input data field attribute on bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, attributes, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to get a data-field attribute to select what field of my "objects.json" will be used as source of my Bootstrap Typeahead input text, like:

form.html

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-field="name">
```

form.js

```
$("[data-provide=typeahead]").typeahead({
  source: function(query, process) {
    return $.get("/objects.json", {
      query: query
    }, function(data) {
      return process($.map(data, function(o) {
        return o[$(this).data('field')];
      }));
    });
  }
});
```

objects.json

```
[{"id":1,"name":"lorem"},
 {"id":2,"name":"ipsum"},
 {"id":3,"name":"dolor"}]
```

The problem is the "$(this).data('field')" on Javascript isn't get the HTML data-field attribute.

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to you, but in my case, I figured that `data-field` does not work. I tried to search online to see if "**field**" is a reserved word but couldn't find anything.
Anyway, changing the `data` attribute to anything else (e.g: `data-myfield`, `data-fieldID`, etc.) worked for me.

Comment: `data-field` isn't reserved by the browser, but maybe it's a Bootstrap convention.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use $(this).attr('data-field')? i also you may want to look here:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ that may also be some of your problem, depending on wether you even get your initial element

Comment: Yes, I've already tried:

`$(this).attr('data-field')
$(this).getAttribute('data-field')
$(this).prop('data-field')
$(this).data('field')`

And nothing works. I get the json data but Typeahead list isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[data-provide=typeahead]").typeahead({
   source: function(query, process) {
     return $.get("/objects.json", {
     query: query
   }, function(data) {
      return process($.map(data, function(o) {
        return o[$(this).attr('data-field')]; //<-- Use attr()
      }));
     });
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried:
`$(this).attr('data-field')
$(this).getAttribute('data-field')
$(this).prop('data-field')
$(this).data('field')`
And nothing works. I get the json data but Typeahead list isn't loaded.